# How to determine whether a pen-drive is being used for the first time in a system?

Tags: usb, installation, drivers, usb-storage

Kindly give a detailed answer. Suppose I have a laptop and a pen-drive, and I insert the pen-drive into the laptop, how do I determine whether the particular pndrive is being used in the system for the first time or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about Windows, this is most-likely due to plug-n-play support. When an unrecognized device is detected (I think primarily using Device ID + Hardware IDs + Compatible IDs, though Vendor_ID and Product_ID might also be used), Windows automatically searches for a driver to install. Though most pen drives just use generic mass storage device drivers, it still has to perform this search process.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB` contains a list of all the devices that have been connected to the machine, including each's VID & PID.

Comment: Adding to this.. flash drives like SanDisk Cruzers also have some sort of software that come with them, that has to be installed the first time (why can't we just have normal flash drives?)

Comment: @ekaj: Are you talking about the U3 autorun software that comes with the U3 Cruzers?

Comment: Ye, or whatever it is.. other flash drives have similar software as well

Comment: @ekaj: Yea, that's most-likely U3 or similar autorun software that's stored on a separate CDFS partition to trick Windows into thinking it's DRM software.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about windows but kindly give me a detailed info on " Suppose I have a laptop and a pen-drive, and I insert the pen-drive into the laptop, how do I determine whether the particular pndrive is being used in the system for the first time or not?" as **I have to solve a case using this.**

Comment: @RishabhPoddar You might want to retitle your question to something that matches the body better. Lese answers the question asked in the title.

Comment: @Rishabh: The registry key I mentioned has a list of all previously attached USB devices. That would be how you determine if a pen drive has been used on the system for the first time.